# How to use Firebase in offline mode in xamarin?

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase in xamarin. It is working good in the online mode.
How can I work with firebase in the offline mode, when there is no internet and sync it to the firebase cloud in the online mode ?

Here is the code I used to create and retrieve data in the online mode :

```
public async Task AddPerson(int personId, string name)
{
    await firebase
      .Child("Persons")
      .PostAsync(new Person() { PersonId = personId, Name = name });
}

public async Task<List<Person>> GetAllPersons()
{
    return (await firebase
      .Child("Persons")
      .OnceAsync<Person>()).Select(item => new Person
      {
          Name = item.Object.Name,
          PersonId = item.Object.PersonId
      }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: You've tagged your question with `google-cloud-firestore`, but are accessing the Realtime Database API in your code. While both database are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and have different APIs. Please either correct the tag or the code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I edited the tag

Comment: For Android/iOS you can enable disk persistence like this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence. Is this available in Xamarin too?

Comment: If you used xamarin forms, you can use `OfflineDatabaseFactory` in the `FirebaseOptions` in offline mode.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT that does not work u should provide an example of this working